# Dual band usb adapter that works with OS X Lion

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-lion

I have a Mac Mini 2007 which has an b/g adapter built into it and would like to use it in a wireless n network. Does anyone know of a dual band usb wireless n adapter that works with OS X Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/feedback/802_11N_Mac_reports.html). Apple uses Broadcom chips, (my System profiler says Broadcom BCM43xx), so those should "just work" I presume.

If it's AirDrop you're after, you need the original Airport Extreme adapter, see [this thread](http://www.tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=25928), or [this](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t259592.html) for example.

Comment: Sounds like upgrading to an airport extreme adapter might be the best bet, thanks :)